# Find Node given a caret position (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML file and I have a supposed caret position. With JS I need to find the html node on which the caret would be placed if it was at the given position.

```
function findNodeForCaretPosition(caretPosition) {
    var node = null; // type Node (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)
  // TODO find node
  return node;
}
```

**Example HTML**

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <p id="a">Time waits for no man. Unless that man is Chuck Norris.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p id="b">Chuck Norris can touch <span id="c" style="color:blue">MC Hammer</span>.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Example HTML plain text**

> Time waits for no man. Unless that man is Chuck Norris.
>
> Chuck Norris can touch MC Hammer.

**Tests**

Caret position = 4 (Time| waits)
Answer = `<p id="a">`

Caret position = 16 (can| touch).
Answer = `<p id="b">`

Caret position = 25 (MC| Hammer).
Answer = `<span id="c">`
Caret position = 1000), no answer (`null`).

Comment: You can use a [`NodeIterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator) to iterate over all the text nodes and count their characters. You can also use the [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) API

Comment: What is the use case here? Why such mapping is needed?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I need to migrate read locators from one epub reader library to another. The old one stores read location as caret position in plain text. The new one stores it in CFI format (Canonical Fragment Identifier). I need to make a conversion between the two. For CFI I need to know a Node which at least approximately matches with the caret position. There's some room for error. I'm allowed to miss by a few nodes. But in general the answer Node has to be close to the caret position.

Comment: What is the caret position relative to? The start of the string?

Comment: @jhpratt Yes. In my example if caret position = 0 it sits right at the start of the string like this `|Time waits`.

Comment: Is it safe to work on the assumption that it's only text and no images/diagrams/whatever?

Comment: @jhpratt in practice there will be cases with images/diagramas, etc. But the most common case is that html will contain text elements only so yes, you can work on that assumption. If the function fails to return correct Node when there are images/diagrams - that's fine with me.

Comment: By the looks if it, the first example is "parented" in the first `div`, while the latter two are in the second? If not, the caret position doesn't make much sense with the numbers you've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've commented the code quite a bit, so I don't think it needs much more of an explanation. Just call `caretPosition` with the parent node and an index as parameters. As strings in JavaScript are UTF-16, any emojis or non-ASCII characters *should* count as one character and not multiple.

Of note, whitespace is important. So the HTML from your question technically wouldn't work, as it first counts newlines and leading spaces. I've removed that here for simplicity.

If you have any questions, let me know in the comments.

```js
/**
 * @param {Element} parent
 * @param {number} index
 */
function caretPosition(parent, index) {
  // The index is too large to fit in the element, return `null` per requirements.
  // We also return `null` if the element isn't a text or element node,
  // as there is no text to check against.
  if (
    (parent.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && index > parent.innerText.length)
    || (parent.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && index > parent.data.length)
    || ![Node.ELEMENT_NODE, Node.TEXT_NODE].includes(parent.nodeType)
  ){
    return null;
  }

  // The length of all text combined to this point
  // (zero is the beginning of `parent`).
  let combinedLength = 0;

  // Iterate over the children until we find
  // the element where we cross the boundry.
  for (const child of parent.childNodes) {
    // Store this in case we need to recurse.
    const previousLength = combinedLength;

    // For the current child, add the length of its text content.
    // As text and element nodes don't share a common property,
    // we need to explicitly check for both. Other node types
    // (such as comments) are irrelevant to the task at hand.
    if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      combinedLength += child.data.length;
    } else if (child.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      combinedLength += child.innerText.length;
    } else {
      // We don't have a text or element node,
      // so there's no text that we could care about.
      // The recursive case will handle the fact that nothing changed,
      // and will return `null`.
      continue;
    }

    // Our cursor is inside or at the end of this node.
    if (index <= combinedLength) {
      // We are in a text node and have nothing to recurse on.
      // Return the parent element of the text node,
      // which is a DOM element.
      if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        return child.parentElement;
      }

      // If we are in an element node, then we have no children.
      // Without children, there is nothing to recurse on;
      // we should return the element.
      // If we are _not_ in an element node,
      // this will be `false`, and we will enter the recursive case.
      else if (child.childElementCount === 0) {
        return child;
      }

      // We have children to iterate over, so do that.
      // It is necessary to change the index to search for
      // as we've got a new reference frame.
      return caretPosition(child, index - previousLength);
    }
  }
}

// Make sure everything works!

const div = document.querySelectorAll('div');

console.assert(caretPosition(div[0], 4) === document.querySelector('#a'));
console.assert(caretPosition(div[1], 16) === document.querySelector('#b'));
console.assert(caretPosition(div[1], 25) === document.querySelector('#c'));
console.assert(caretPosition(div[0], 1000) === null);
console.assert(caretPosition(div[1], 1000) === null);
```

```html
<div><p id='a'>Time waits for no man. Unless that man is Chuck Norris.</p></div>
<div><p id='b'>Chuck Norris can touch <span id='c' style='color:blue'>MC Hammer</span>.</p></div>
```